# Missing FSI.exe from F# pipeline (sometimes)

Tags: azure-devops, f#, yaml, azure-pipelines

Hej, I have a YML pipeline and am having issues with FSI.exe which I am using for running f# scripts.

The problem is unreliability, sometimes I will get fsi.exe not found when running the pipeline. Othertimes it succeds without any prior changes to the code or YML, just by rerunning it.

```
  fsiPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe'
```

[Pipeline Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qHXX.png)

example from success:

```
Pool: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
Agent: Hosted Agent
Started: Today at 12:53 PM
Duration: 4m 59s

Job preparation parameters
2 artifacts produced
100% tests passed
```

Example from failure

```
Pool: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
Agent: Hosted Agent
Started: Today at 2:12 PM
Duration: 1m 16s
```

So I am using the same agent on both cases

yml section: (some names have been changed, but in essence the fsi path is the issue)

```
trigger: 
  branches:
    include: 
    - main

pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  demands:
  - npm
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

variables:
  BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  BuildConfiguration: 'release'
  Solution: '.......sln'
  targetFolder: .........'
  fsiPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Solution)'

- task: isaacabraham.fsharp-helpers-extension.1ba72b0a-f476-4a91-90a0-b8e7a0cc4337.FSharpScript@1
  displayName: '.....'
  inputs:
    ScriptFile: '$(targetFolder)/target/script.fsx'
    ScriptArguments: '/target="$(env)" /method=client /id="$(DevOps-ClientID)" /secret="$(DevOps-ClientSecret)"'
    FsiPathSelection: Custom
    CustomPath: '$(fsiPath)'
```

Comment: Is this .NET Core or .NET 5? `fsi.exe` is no longer a thing, you're supposed to run it as a `dotnet` tool, like `dotnet fsi path/to/my/script.fsx`

Comment: `fsi.exe` (or `fsiAnyCpu.exe` for 64-bit) is still needed for .NET Framework projects. `dotnet fsi` only works for .NET Core/.NET 5.

Comment: It is .net framework 4.62

Answer (score 1):

Someone has else asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800998/githubactions-ci-windows-vms-dont-have-fsi-exe-anymore-or-it-changed-location). It looks like the location of `fsi.exe` has changed in a recent release of VS2019:

- VS2019 version 16.9.3: `...\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe`
- VS2019 version 16.10.0: `...\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools\fsi.exe`

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution, while not pretty**

I kept getting the issue: cannot find fsi.exe.

Sometimes it would run 10+ times in a row with no issues, to suddenly be infected by this on the 11th run (I am assuming it is due to the VMs being different).

My workaround is to include the fsi.exe (all its dlls) in the ropo and reference them.

Added folder (From my local PC)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp

to

Repo/Tools/Fsharp, then I changed my fsipath

```
  fsiPath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Tools/FSharp/fsi.exe"
```