# Could not find fsi.exe. Attempting to resolve fsi.exe in PATH

Tags: azure, path, azure-pipelines, devops

I am new to Azure Pibelines, but try to learn it. It seems very powerfull.

Have got at .netcore31 project who works/compiles fine with 'agent specification' "windows-2019", but when I update to .net6 and "windows-2022" or "windows-latest" I got the subtitle error "Could not find fsi.exe. Attempting to resolve fsi.exe in PATH".

Have read [Missing FSI.exe from F# pipeline (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739100/missing-fsi-exe-from-f-pipeline-sometimes) and others, but ... maybe I miss ssome basic informations.

The Pibeline has step for NuGet 5.4.0, NuGet rastore, and build solutionXXX.

The solution works fine on my own machine with VS2022, and in the pibeling with VS2019. Know that fsi.exe has another path, 19<>22, but ... do I have to set that path myselves (how) on a Azure Pibeline?

VS19: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools\fsi.exe
VS22: c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools\fsi.exe

Other helps are velcome (?), thanks a lot.

Comment: What about adding 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools' into Control panel->Edit the system environment variables->System Properties->Environment Variables then have a try to run the affected pipeline?

Comment: Sounds correct, but how!? I can't log on a pipeline, but yes somehow ... there must be a  "agent step" where I can add a path. Look for it ...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in local using the command line as an administrator and it could be added successfully:

```
setx /M path "%Path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools"
```

So could you kindly try to add a task before the failed build task for a try:

[image]

Here is the script for your reference.

```
steps:
- script: 'setx /M path "%Path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools"'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Comment: Thanks, but ...
1)
Path seems now correct. Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;...
But the next step still returne this error: Could not find fsi.exe. Attempting to resolve fsi.exe in PATH

Comment: Could you share the debuglog of the error, the pipeline definition(which task are you using) and related settings for the fsi.exe for troubleshoot? You could edit your question, thanks.